# Dailog box not visible when custom control is added in MFC Dailog Application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

i have add custom control on dailog box in MFC Dailog application.when i run my code dailog box is not visible.

anyone having any idea how to fix this??

Comment: Probably by fixing the custom control. Without seeing any code, there's not much we can do. Please provide a [mcve]. Even though the link thoroughly explains, what an MCVE is, I'm having a feeling that I need to re-iterate, that it should be **minimal** and complete.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Usually it's because the window class (`WNDCLASS`) of the custom control has not been registered (`RegisterClass()`) yet.  Make sure you register the class first.